# Serialization/deserialization problems with classes derived from ArrayList when passed via Bundle

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

Let's suppose I've got such entity

```
public class Zone implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4671106665561808440L;

    private String id;

   public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

public static final class List extends ArrayList<Zone>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8772227355586038754L;

    public List() {
        super();
    }

    public List(Collection<? extends Zone> collection) {
        super(collection);
    }

    public List(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

}
```

And trying to pass it with intent via following way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ZonesListActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_ZONES, zones);
```

The problem is when I am trying to deserialize via following code

```
Zone.List zones = (Zone.List) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRAS_ZONES);
```

I've got ClassCastException (ArrayList could not be casted to Zone.List). Could you please explain me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Give try this

```
intent.putSerializable(EXTRAS_ZONES, zones);
```

Comment: A very offtopic question. What does this statement means, do you know?  (Zone.List) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRAS_ZONES)  Does two methods getIntent() and getSerializableExtra (EXTRAS_ZONES) are called at same time with this statement? Java supports such way to call two methods with just one statement?